# Azure Function Kafka Trigger does not process events even when there is more than 1 partition

Tags: .net, azure, apache-kafka, azure-functions

#### Situation:

We have a Kafka topic with 10 partitions and an Azure Function listening to the topic with Kafka trigger. The main purpose of having 10 partitions is to process everything parallelly. **We don't care about the order**. Even we are fine with processing events from a single partition parallelly.

#### Observation:

Even with multiple partitions, Azure Function doesn't process events from multiple partitions parallelly.

[image]

#### Question:

1. Is it the intended behavior? or Is it a bug?
2. If this is the intended behavior, then **is there a configuration to process events parallelly?** (We care only about throughput, doesn't care about order)
3. Is there a way to process events parallelly with a single partition? (Without using IsBatched `true` and parallel processing it ourself)

#### Environment:

**Runtime:** .Net7 Isolated
**Package Version:** 3.6.0
**Hosting Plan:**  Dedicated (App Service) plan

Answer (score 0):

Eventhub and Kafka are very similar. If you look at the documentation [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/event-hubs/partitioning-in-event-hubs-and-kafka#determine-the-number-of-partitions), it says the following :

> Use more partitions to achieve more throughput. Each consumer reads
> from its assigned partition. So with more partitions, more consumers
> can receive events from a topic at the same time.  Use at least as many partitions as the value of your target throughput in megabytes.    To avoid starving consumers, use at least as many partitions as
> consumers. For instance, suppose eight partitions are assigned to
> eight consumers. Any additional consumers that subscribe will have to
> wait. Alternatively, you can keep one or two consumers ready to
> receive events when an existing consumer fails.

What this means is that the number of partitions are > 1 so that multiple consumers/servers can consume the data in parallel. If you are using an app service without any scaling, it can only read from 1 partition at a time. If however, your app service scaled up to an instance count > 1 then they would start reading the messages from separate partitions in parallel. Each server of the consumer can only be connected to one partition at a time.

What you can try is setup some auto scaling rules to scale the app service or use consumption or premium function plans. The instance count should then increase depending on load and consume data from all partitions in parallel.

Comment: Interesting, is that mean there is no way to process events in parallel with a single Azure Function instance? I don't care about the order of events

Comment: Not really no. The use of partitions only increases throughput/scale if you have multiple servers reading the Kafka topic in parallel. You cannot achieve the same throughput using only 1 server as that would be the bottle neck in your solution.

Comment: The issue I am facing is that each event takes 1 min to process in my case. What I am observing is that Azure Function only processes 1 event every minute. Which is very slow. I want the Azure function to process multiple events at the same time. My underlying system (DB, Dependent Service, etc) is definitely capable of processing multiple events parallelly.

Comment: Why not just switch to consumption functions or setup auto scaling rules so that your function scales up to multiple instances? Even though each event may take 1 minute to process that does not mean that your function will process only 1 event per min. It will fetch multiple events in a batch but from the same partition. Your requirement is to process from all partitions in parallel. The only way to do that is if you had more consumer instances. Also what trigger are you  using for your function? You should be using the native Kafka trigger.

Comment: Details of the Kafka binding/trigger can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-kafka?pivots=programming-language-csharp&tabs=in-process%2Cportal. It clearly details that you can control the batchsize meaning number of events that your function will read at a time.

Comment: My requirement is to process events in parallel (even with single partition, doesn't care about no of partitions, can inc or dec if need). Even I tried to increase the MaxBatchSize to 500, still its processing one event at a time (which means its taking 500 mins to process 500 events). Yes, I am using the Kafka Trigger in Isolated mode.

Comment: I have added Image in the post showing my observation